# How to secure swagger page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui, http-authentication

In my project there is a documentation of API's by using swagger which URL is like **http//www.example.com/api**. Issue is that these are public and anyone can see that. I want to secure this link so that anyone can't see these API's.

I see `http_authentication` and `basic_authentication` but it can't work on swagger because it is in public. How I secure that page?

Comment: do use use devise? you can mount it only for users based on some criteria.

Comment: No i am not using devise

Comment: you don't have any authentication?

Comment: have authentication. Its authentication for page not login etc

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP autentication can be done on Nginx (or Apache) level.

Comment: seems like very bad design, doesn't it?

Comment: Why? If it will be plugged under unobvious route, IMHO can be an appriopriate solution.

Comment: As for me I don't like to mess up application logic with HTTP server configuration. Maybe I don't understand something is it somehow better than using rails http basic authentication?

Comment: True, but as I understood, he can not do it in Rails controller, because the request doesn't go through a controller but directly access the pregenerated files in `public` dir.